# Determining access level of a field

Tags: java, reflection, field, access-levels

I am wondering what - if this is even possible - the method of determining the access level of a field (private/protected/public) in java.

What I want to do is find out if there is any protected fields in a class. This is the method I have so far in my base abstract class:

```
public boolean hasOptions() {
    for (Field field : getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
        // Method to determine if field is protected.
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I've looked around without being able to find an answer.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, use the `static` utility methods of the [`Modifier`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Modifier.html) class. For example

```
Modifier.isProtected(field.getModifiers());
```